# Ожидание результата выполнения команды в TCL

Tags: tcl

Всем привет. 
Подскажите как правильно описать ожидание выполнения команды в TCL?
Есть команда:

```
server: echo $?
1
server:
```

Как правильно написать expect, чтобы он увидел эту 1 ??
Пробовал так, но не получается

```
$conn1 send "echo \$?\r"
$conn1 wait -expect "1"
$conn1 send -key ESCAPE
$conn1 wait -expect ": "
```

Ошибка:

```
server: echo $?
1
server:

ERROR: timeout
ERROR:     while executing
ERROR: "$conn1 wait -expect "1""
```